# How to have a C++ library callable by multiple languages?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, ffi

My team has built a C++ library that needs to be callable by Java on Android, but should also be callable by other languages as well: Swift, Flutter, other C++ codebases, etc...

The challenge is that we don't want to have to manually update the various FFIs (JNI, Obj-C++, Dart FFI, etc...) every time we update the API.
What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: On paper, that's what [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is for, but it's not exactly a joy to maintain.

Comment: You have to write a wrapper if you are to call it from any managed code. One way around it is to provide a REST interface. It really depends on the application - you usually right code in C++ for performance reasons, REST + JSON will probably kill any performance gains you got from using C++

Comment: You probably want to expose the functionality as `extern "C"`, since the C calling convention / ABI is much broader supported than the C++ one (which may even vary between compilers).

Comment: You need to be less generic.  There are many ways to make FFIs and which is best depend son what your library *does*.  A library that wraps raster operations on pixel buffers, a library that provides an object like a matrix and does efficient multiplication on it, and a windowing library would have very different ways to expose themselves...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have one callable function in the library that takes a string or a byte array. That string/array can be JSON or a serialized Google protocol buffer. The same method can be used for returning values from your function.

This way you implement FFIs once, but pay a serialization/deserialization fee at run-time.